# Sending data to a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm currently working on an app where you can make your own notifications (Just for the fun). You can customize them in (almost) any way.

My problem is: I don't know how to get the data from the main activity to my notification service.

This is how the Intent that I'm using right now is looking like:

```
Intent startNotificationServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notification.class);
            startNotificationServiceIntent
                    .putExtra("Title", title)
                    .putExtra("Text", text)
                    .putExtra("Millis", millis)
                    .putExtra("IsImportant", isImportant);

            startService(startNotificationServiceIntent);
```

And this is the onStartCommand right now:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    displayNotification(/*Currently empty*/);
    stopSelf();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

And this is the method (displayNotification) that I'm using to create the notification:

```
private void displayNotification(String title, String text, long VibrationLongMillis, boolean isImportant) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.attention)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, VibrationLongMillis, VibrationLongMillis, VibrationLongMillis})
            .setSound(uri)
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text));

    if (isImportant) {
        notification.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());

}
```

Comment: what data do you want to send ? please be more descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the information in the `Intent` (as you are already doing it) and then read it in your Service like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
    /* Do here the same for the other parameters */
    displayNotification(title, text, vibrationLongMillis, isImportant);
    stopSelf();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```